# Only Get A Partial Sorting

Tags: c++

I am using a natural merge sort method, and when I test it on an array of ints in exact order (81,7,211,23,57,91,43,11,64,43), My output is down below, I am only off by 1 number so it seems like it sorts part of it but I cant figure out why the other is not getting sorted. Anyone have any suggestions?why?

```
void naturalMS(int * a, int s)
    {
    for(int i = 1; i < s; i *= 2)
    {
       for(int low = 0; low < s- i; low += i*2)
       {
           merge(a,s,low,s-1,low+i-1);
           cout << "i: " << i << "   low: " << low << endl;

       }
    }
}
void merge(int *a, int size, int low, int high, int mid)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int *c = new int[size];
    i = low;
    k = low;
    j = mid + 1;
    while (i <= mid && j <= high)
    {
        if (a[i] < a[j])
        {
           c[k] = a[i];
           k++;
           i++;
       }
       else
       {
           c[k] = a[j];
           k++;
           j++;
       }
    }
    while (i <= mid)
    {
       c[k] = a[i];
       k++;
       i++;
    }
    while (j <= high)
    {
      c[k] = a[j];
      k++;
      j++;
    }
   for (i = low; i < k; i++)
   {
       a[i] = c[i];
   }
}
```

> Beginning: 
>     81,7,211,23,57,91,43,11,64,43
>
> OutPut:
>     7,11,23,43,57,43,64,81,91,211
>
> 1. i: 1   low : 0
> 2. i: 1   low : 2
> 3. i: 1   low : 4
> 4. i: 1   low : 6
> 5. i: 1   low : 8
> 6. i: 2   low : 0
> 7. i: 2   low : 4
> 8. i: 4   low : 0
> 9. i: 8   low : 0

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Just wanted a little help lol

Comment: The debugger is one of the most helpful thing your toolchain gives you.

Comment: Yes agreed, i was able to find out what it outputs.

Comment: @Thompson So, in using the debugger, you should've been able to step through your code, so you could observe where the code deviates from your expectations.

Comment: I was able to make some changes, I am now off by 1 number and I'm about to rip my hair out lol. The 43, is sitting next to the 57 for some reason, wonder if its because I have 2 43s.

Comment: No I changed that 43 to a 29, and it still give me the same answer, but with a 29. So i'm assuming the problem is coming from that spot.

Comment: Start with smaller, and less arbitrary, test cases.